# PHP preg_replace URI's in phpBB

Tags: php, regex, string, blob, phpbb3

I'm trying to replace some image URI's in some phpBB forum post content retrieved from the DB for an external page.

```
preg_replace('/((https?|ftp).*\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg))/i', '<img src="$1" alt "" />','http://somesite.com/image.png awordcontainingpng');
```

The above works well and as expected.

The thing is, when I try to apply the same to the MySQL result, nothing gets matched.  Matches seem to work when I remove the escaped dot

E.g.:

```
preg_replace('/((https?|ftp).*(gif|png|jpg|jpeg))/i', '<img src="$1" />',$phpbb_post);
```

But that's no good.  The data is BLOB type - I don't know if that makes a difference.  Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Give us some example data that we have something to work with.

Comment: Hi.  I have the issue with any old image URI, e.g. http://somesite.com/image.png awordcontainingpng.  Somehow the replace just doesn't work when applied to the MySQL result, but works on a string added manually as the subject.

Comment: Please add result for `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query); echo $row['text']` (or however you get your results) to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHPBB, when the images are saved into the database, they are totally encoded. This means that the dot `.` is replaced by a `&#46;`.

Comment: Thank you! /((https?|ftp).*&#46;(gif|png|jpg|jpeg))/i.  That's done it.

Answer (score 0):

when you load Image directly from MYSQL you do it this way

so assuming you can retrieve image data follow it with this and save files as display.php

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Images` WHERE `id` = $id"; // $id is what you pass from your img src
$image = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query($sql));
header("Content-length: " . $image->size); // $image is your object
header("Content-type: " . $image->type); // say image/png
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $image->name);
echo $image->data;
die();
```

and from  your HTML call this

```
<img src="display.php?id=YOUR_DB_REC_ID" />
```

Comment: This does not apply to phpBB and should never be used within phpBB.

PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS METHOD IN PHPBB IF TRYING TO FIND THE ANSWER!

Comment: `sql = 'SELECT post_text
FROM ' . POST_DATA  
. " WHERE user_id='{$row['user_id']}'";

$result = $db->sql_query($sql);

// Retrieve the row data.
$row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);

$db->sql_freeresult($result);`

Above is the correct syntax